# Compute accuracy of model evaluation

Tags: predictive-models, accuracy, model-evaluation, confusion-matrix

Say the number of negativ classes is $9990$ and the number of positive classes is $10$.
If a model predicts all examples to belong to the negative class, how accurate is this prediction?

So what we got:

- Actual positive (TP): 10
- Actual negative (TN): 9990
- Predicted positive (FP): 0
- Predicted negativ (FN): 10000

So the accuracy would be: $\frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN} = \frac{10+10000}{10+10000+0+10000)} = 0.5$

But it doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: TP is "True Positive" (predicted positive and actually positive: $0$ here). TN is "True Negative" (predicted negative and actually negative: $9990$ here).  FP is "False Positive" (predicted positive and actually negative: $0$ here). FN is "False Negative" (predicted negative and actually positive: $10$ here).

Comment: Despite the question starting with important definitional errors, this Q/A is a concise and useful reference for new stats learners.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's wrong.

FN = false negative = 10

FP = false positive = 0

TP = true positive = 0

TN = true negative = 9990

accuracy = $\frac{9990 + 0}{10 + 9990 + 0 + 0}$ = 99.9%

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}$?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I've changed it.

Comment: I think TP should be 0, as nothing has been classified positive. $\frac{0+9990}{0+9990+0+10} = 99.9\%$

Comment: Wow, i'm failing here. I'm pretty sure it is now correct.